# Criterion for unicity and existence of pre-image in multivariate cryptography

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms, cryptography, multivariate-polynomial

I am reading Ding's [Multivariate Public Key Cryptosystems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-0716-0987-3) and in the book the author explains the so-called *bipolar construction* where one chooses three maps to construct encryption and signature schemes.
The vector spaces we consider are $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $\mathbb{F}^m$ where $\mathbb{F}:=\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field. Two of those maps are affine (usually denoted $\mathcal{S}:\mathbb{F}^m\to\mathbb{F}^m$ and $\mathcal{T}:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^n$) and the third one $\mathcal{F}:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^m$ (usually called the central map) is a system of $m$ multivariate quadratic polynomials in $n$ variables that is supposed to be "easily invertible". One then considers the public key $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{S}\circ\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{T}$. To encrypt a message $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}^n$ one then simply computes $\mathbf{z}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{z})$. The decryption then follows recursively by setting $\mathbf{x} = \mathcal{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{w})$ and so on.

Then on page 15, the author makes the following claim:

> If $m\geq n$, the pre-image of $\mathbf{x}$ by $\mathcal{F}$ i.e. $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ is unique.

It is not clear in my mind why this is true. The map $\mathcal{F}$ is not linear, is it? It's made up of quadratic multivariate polynomials. Why should the resulting pre-image be unique?

Likewise, for signature schemes (still on page 15), we now consider $n\leq m$ and the author makes this claim:

> If $n\geq m$, then the pre-image $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ always exists and there might be multiple.

Why is this true? I thought that the map being easily invertible necessarily made it so that a pre-image exists.

Comment: Good comment, let me check and I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I only read your question and may be misunderstanding but here goes:

You say

> The vector spaces we consider are $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $\mathbb{F}^m$ where $\mathbb{F}:=\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field. Two of those maps are affine (usually denoted $\mathcal{S}:\mathbb{F}^m\to\mathbb{F}^m$ and $\mathcal{T}:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^n$) and the third one $\mathcal{F}:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^m$ (usually called the central map) is a system of $m$ multivariate quadratic polynomials in $n$ variables that is supposed to be "easily invertible". One then considers the public key $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{S}\circ\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{T}$. To encrypt a message $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}^n$ one then simply computes $\mathbf{z}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{z})$. The decryption then follows recursively by setting $\mathbf{x} = \mathcal{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{w})$ and so on.

You ask why it would be true that:

> If $m\geq n$, the pre-image of $\mathbf{x}$ by $\mathcal{F}$ i.e. $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ is unique.

If the domain is smaller than the range and the function is well defined the pre-image always exists (possibly empty if some $y$ in the range is not hit) and has cardinality zero (empty set) or one (otherwise). Thus the pre-image is unique.

> Likewise, for signature schemes (still on page 15), we now consider $n\leq m$ and the author makes this claim:
> If $n\geq m$, then the pre-image $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ always exists and there might be multiple.

Here the function is mapping to a smaller domain so multiple inputs may map to the same output.

Comment: But it says this is true for any $x$, so the fact the pre-image might be empty is a problem. Nowhere in the definition does it say the function has to be injective or surjective, so you cannot (I believe) reason that the "domain is smaller than the range", or anything like that. As an example, consider $x\mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

Comment: If you want to allow a function to be defined only on part of the domain then you cannot conclude anything at all. In which case your question is impossible to answer. Never have I seen such a state of affairs in cryptographic literature based on finite sets.

Comment: Can you explain why the domain being "smaller" than the range implies that the pre-image is unique? Is it because we're working over finite fields?